# vbscript - how to use files one by one by first number?

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

can you give me an advice?

I'm working on windows and using MS power point and I would like to automatically use my picure files

they are named like

```
1_MOD_82.1542.bmp
2_MOD_102.8821.bmp
3_MOD_152.3541.bmp
```

and so on.. and I would like to use it instead of typing

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="F:\somedir\1_MOD_82.1542"
```

So I would like to have some loop like (but this code is idea only, not working)

```
for i:=0, i++,i<10 do
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:="F:\somedir\%i*"
```

I want to make a loop which will use image files by starting number.

Answer (score 0):

Add an inner loop:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i = 0 To 9
  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("F:\somedir").Files
    If f.Type = "Bitmap-Image" Then
      If CInt(Left(f.Name, 1)) = i Then
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(f.Path)
      End If
    End If
  Next
Next
```

A check to make sure that the first character is a number could be added like this:

```
If f.Type = "Bitmap-Image" Then
  c = Left(f.Name, 1)
  If IsNumeric(c) Then
    If CInt(c) = i Then
      '...
    End If
  End If
End If
```

Another (more elaborate) option for processing the images would be to enumerate them into a disconnected [recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the recordset. That way you wouldn't have to enumerate all files in the images folder with every loop cycle.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rs  = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
rs.Fields.Append "Name", 200, 80
rs.Fields.Append "Path", 200, 255
rs.Open

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("F:\somedir").Files
  If f.Type = "Bitmap-Image" Then
    rs.AddNew
    rs("Name").Value = f.Name
    rs("Path").Value = f.Path
    rs.Update
  End If
Next

For i = 0 To 9
  rs.Filter = "Name LIKE '" & i & "%'"
  rs.MoveFirst
  Do Until rs.EOF
    ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(rs("Path").Value)
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
Next
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Wiechers, anyway I tried your script and it gives me a Runtime error 13 Type mismatch by line     If f.Type = "Bitmap-Image" And CInt(Left(f.Name, 1)) = i Then .. I tried also only If CInt(Left(f.Name, 1)) = i Then and still error 13, what it can be? thank you!

Comment: @Ondrej Sorry, my mistake. I keep forgetting that VBScript will always evaluate all conditions even if the first check already failed. Because of that the script tries to convert the first character of all file names, even if they are not bitmaps. If your folder contains bitmaps whose name doesn't start with a number, you'll need another check that will verify if the first character actually is a number.

Comment: it is working now when there are only "number-named" files.. thanks a LOT!

Comment: it is working now when there are only "number-named" files.. thanks a LOT! but Now I realized that I must have name of files like:  M_1_MOD_1542.124512.bmp and M_2_MOD_2482.1823648 so.. the number by M_xx is important for import order (it can be from 1 to 99).. how to process this? because my export software do only M_xx numbering, not xx_ numbering.. can you help me with the code? thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Replace `Left(f.Name, 1)` with `Replace(Mid(f.Name, 3, 2), "_", "")`.